How to trigger pipeline only when there is a merge request completes in azure devops
I have two different repos and one single pipeline and need to trigger the pipeline only when there is a merge request completes in repoB.

trigger:
  - develop

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: repoA
      type: git
      name: sk/repoA
      ref: refs/heads/develop
      
    - repository: repoB
      type: git
      name: sk/repoB
      ref: refs/heads/develop
      trigger: 
        branches:
          include:
            - develop
      

Used this above yaml but it is triggering when ever there is a change in develop branch

"it is triggering when ever there is a change in develop branch" - well, you have defined a trigger for that branch :-)

What is the repository of the pipeline? And what is the target branch of the pull request? main? master? ...

Pipeline is in develop branch
`trigger:

develop`

all are in develop branch

To trigger the pipeline from another branch do I need any configuration changes..?

Is the pipeline also in project "sk"? If so, you can create webhook for PR update and then use webhook to trigger your pipeline. I will share the details below.

yes all are in same project

Hi @Saikumar, I have shared the detailed steps. You can try it in your pipeline.

The webhook trigger also can work when the pipeline and repoB are not in the same project, even not the same organization. See my answer below.

You can use the Service Hooks together with Webhooks resource to trigger the pipeline only when the PR is successfully completed in RepoB.

In the Azure DevOps project where RepoB is in, go to Project Settings > Service Hooks to create a new subscription following the steps below:

Select "Web Hooks" as the service. Then Next.


On the Trigger section, select RepoB. The target branch can be [Any] or a particular branch existing in RepoB. Select "Status changed" as the type of Change. Then Next.


The request URL is with format "https://dev.azure.com/<organization-name>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<webhook-name>?api-version=6.0-preview". The <organization-name> is the name of your Azure DevOps organization where the pipeline is in. And <webhook-name> is a custom name of the webhook. Then Finish.
For example, here I set the webhook name as 'PR-Completed'.
https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/PR-Completed?api-version=6.0-preview





In the Azure DevOps project where the pipeline is in, go to Project Settings > Service connections to create a new Incoming WebHook service connection.

WebHook Name: The value should be consistent with the webhook name set in the request URL above.
Service connection name: A custom name of the service connection.



In the pipeline, you can configure like as below.
# azure-pipelines.yml

trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repoA
    type: git
    name: sk/repoA
    ref: refs/heads/develop
  - repository: repoB
    type: git
    name: sk/repoB
    ref: refs/heads/develop

  webhooks:
  - webhook: PR_Completed
    connection: PR-Completed-Connection
    filters:
    - path: resource.status
      value: completed

variables:
  PR_repoName: ${{ parameters.PR_Completed.resource.repository.name }}
  PR_id: ${{ parameters.PR_Completed.resource.pullRequestId }}
  PR_title: ${{ parameters.PR_Completed.resource.title }}
  PR_sourceBranch: ${{ parameters.PR_Completed.resource.sourceRefName }}
  PR_targetBranch: ${{ parameters.PR_Completed.resource.targetRefName }}
  PR_status: ${{ parameters.PR_Completed.resource.status }}
  PR_mergeStatus: ${{ parameters.PR_Completed.resource.mergeStatus }}

steps:
. . .

- bash: |
    echo "resources.triggeringAlias = $(resources.triggeringAlias)"
    echo "resources.triggeringCategory = $(resources.triggeringCategory)"
    echo "PR_repoName = $(PR_repoName)"
    echo "PR_id = $(PR_id)"
    echo "PR_title = $(PR_title)"
    echo "PR_sourceBranch = $(PR_sourceBranch)"
    echo "PR_targetBranch = $(PR_targetBranch)"
    echo "PR_status = $(PR_status)"
    echo "PR_mergeStatus = $(PR_mergeStatus)"






To trigger the pipeline only when there is a merge request completes in repoB, you can create webhook for PR update and then use webhook to trigger your pipeline. See the details below.

Create a webhook.
Go to Project Settings -> Service hook -> Plus button -> WebHooks -> Next



Trigger on this type of event: Pull request updated
Repository: repoB
Target branch: The target branch of your PR. For me, it's main.



URL: https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/{WebhookName}?api-version=6.0-preview. For me, the name of the webhook is WebhookPR.


Create an Incoming WebHook service connection.
Go to Project Settings -> Service connections -> Select Incoming WebHook


WebHook Name: The webhook name you set above.
Service connection name: The name of your service connection. It's WebhookPR-SC for me.


Add a webhook resource to your pipeline and add a filter to ensure it is triggered when PR is completed.


trigger:
  - none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: repoA
      type: git
      name: sk/repoA
      ref: refs/heads/develop
      
    - repository: repoB
      type: git
      name: sk/repoB
      ref: refs/heads/develop

  webhooks:
    - webhook: WebhookPR         ### Webhook alias
      connection: WebhookPR-SC    ### Incoming webhook service connection
      filters:
        - path: resource.status
          value: completed


Result
When PR is completed in repoB, the pipeline will be triggered as shown below.




Used this above yaml but it is triggering when ever there is a change in develop branch

It is because you have configured CI trigger for develop branch and the repo resource trigger is also configured for develop branch. I have removed them in the yaml above.
Official docs for your reference:

Generic webhook based triggers for YAML pipelines.
resources.repositories.repository definition.

